# APP Reject on Itunes

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I have uploaded app on iTunes and iTunes rejected app continuously and provided crashlog. I have found issue like "**-[AFNetworkReachabilityManager .cxx_destruct]**".

Actually i have add AFNetworking using pods and i have also check latest version and it is there.

If any one have any idea about this problem then let me know.

Thanks in Advance.

I have attached all crash log

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000186ec3014 0x186ea4000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000186f8b450 0x186f86000 + 21584
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000186e3749c 0x186dd4000 + 406684
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000186e3740c 0x186dd4000 + 406540
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001869012d4 0x186900000 + 4820
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018691ecc0 0x186900000 + 126144
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018692c844 0x186924000 + 34884
7   AppName                         0x000000010050294c 0x1000c4000 + 4450636
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018691b66c 0x186900000 + 112236
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018691b234 0x186900000 + 111156
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018692c71c 0x186924000 + 34588
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187dce32c 0x187dc5000 + 37676
12  UIKit                           0x000000018de0e7b0 0x18dd94000 + 501680
13  UIKit                           0x000000018de09534 0x18dd94000 + 480564
14  APPName                         0x00000001001699b4 0x1000c4000 + 678324
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000186db15b8 0x186dad000 + 17848
```

and iTunes provided me simple below message.

For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please see Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing Application Crash Reports.

For additional information about supporting IPv6 Networks, please refer to Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks and Supporting IPv6-only Networks.

For a networking overview, please see About Networking.

If you have any questions about the information provided, please reply to this message and we will get back to you as soon as we can.

Best regards,
App Store Review

Comment: PLease post the full crash log.

Comment: Also add the reason giving by apple guys for rejection.

Comment: kindly share the email end to you be apple about crash log or Kindly share the full detail of the error

Comment: convert above log using Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing Application Crash Reports. and upload in your question

Comment: To get what's wrong with your IPA, check [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

Comment: i have checked in link and i have already check and in this i have found **"-0x06783240 (in APP NAME)
-[AFNetworkReachabilityManager .cxx_destruct] (in APP NAME) (AFNetworkReachabilityManager.m:114)"**

Comment: That is just one line, please post the symbolised crashlog.

Answer (score 0):

It may case that your application network is not support IPV6 network. So apple will reject your application.

Check below points into your application:

1) Make sure you API link which you used in your application, doesn't have any ip address. If you calling API using IPAddress then your application will rejected.

2) Do testing your application using IPV6 network thorugh your system. Here is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1).